# JFrame saving user selections to a .txt file?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm working on this swing project and thought it would be a good idea to save user selections to a text file so whenever program is closed and opened again old selections still persist there. Mainly want to store things like checked checkboxes, radio buttons and some integer variables. Is this possible to do in just plain .txt file or will I have to use something like xml?

This should be done with intention to then grab info from txt file and use to set latest user selections in JFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact use of property files.

Its just a matter of setting properties and saving to a property file and getting these properties at load time. Define the items you need saving in key value pairs when saving. You can retrieve from the key when reading.

For example for a radio button have the property write as ;

```
prop.setProperty("radioselected", "true"); //true or false based on the selection
```

When reading,

```
boolean radioSelected = Boolean.parseBoolean(prop.getProperty("radioselected"))
```

If this value is true, set the radio button checked state true when loading the UI. If not keep it unchecked.

Refer http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) for this, although, creating an object to hold the information and store it in XML using JAXB is also nice and a little more flexible (in my opinion) since the XML structure allows for more of a tree-like structure, allowing for saving more complex information, and for keeping related stuff together. There's no automatic way to do this, and so you the programmer will have to write code for this. If your program is set up as an MVC, Model-View-Control, type program, you'll simply save the model, perhaps via JAXB as I've mentioned.

Comment: +1 for [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html); for reference, `java.util.Preferences` uses XML on Mac/Linux and th registry on Windows.

Comment: @trashgod: thanks for the info. FWIW, I hate the Windows registry. I have no idea what dead ends and ghosts inhabit that beast.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, use the [Java™ Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/), the page says it:

> Applications require preference and configuration data to adapt to the
>   needs of different users and environments. The **java.util.prefs** package
>   provides a way for applications to store and retrieve user and system
>   preference and configuration data. The data is stored persistently in
>   an implementation-dependent backing store. There are two separate
>   trees of preference nodes, one for user preferences and one for system
>   preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular text files. It's only a matter of encoding the data from your program into text and decoding the text into the form when loading.

As the other answers suggest, you can also use properties to not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Use properties file. To save it when window is closing use code like following:

```
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            saveProperties();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I had a quick read on this, and I think I understand how to save certain information from variables, but how would I save a state of checkbox or radio button for example? so they display as selected on a next run. Could you please expand on this.

Comment: @Ilja: that will all depend on your program set up. There's no automatic way to do this, and so you the programmer will have to write code for this. If your program is set up as an MVC, Model-View-Control, type program, you'll simply save the model.